# Access to AWS Kinesis tables in DynamoDB using AWS Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I am new to AWS Kinesis. Trying to learn how to build distributed application using AWS DynamoDB. Could someone tell me how to access the tables in DynamoDB used by my streams in AWS Kinesis using the AWS Cli? Can I query the tables?

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement? What tables are they and how are they populated? Are you saying that you have a DynamoDB table configured to produce DynamoDB Streams when data is added/changed/deleted? Please explain your system, how it is configured and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well I am using AWS Kinesis as a durable queue, with a pub sub architecture, where all my services communicates using it. Kinesis uses DynamoDB to store the application states as per the documentation in AWS. I wanted to know how can I see these using AWS Cli? This would help me understand how checkpointing and grace shutdown works and implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "Kinesis uses DynamoDB to store the application states as per the documentation"? Could you provide a link to the referenced documentation? Amazon Kinesis does not store data in DynamoDB unless you specifically code this.

Comment: Sure here is the required documentation, [link(]http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-ddb.html) hopefully this helps.

Comment: The DynamoDB tables referenced in that documentation page are used to manage the state of applications that are using the [Kinesis Client Library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-java.html). Are you writing code that uses the KCL? Or are you looking for general advice about how you might use Kinesis?

Comment: I am using the KCL Library. Do we have access to these tables? If so how to I access them?

Comment: That documentation page says "You can view the table using the Amazon DynamoDB console while the application is running". I don't know why you'd want to access these tables as they are simply used to manage the KCL processes. They are not a reliable way to access your Kinesis messages themselves.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, to see how the application states are saved. Is there any documentation on DynamoDB tables specific for the KCL application? And how to access them using the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely. Kinesis-stream uses Amazon Dynamodb table for consumer offset management.

- your table will have the same name as your consumer name (defined via KCL). you can see all consumer_offset_tables via console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home)
- consumer could be running in multiple instances, but only one instance (THE `leaseOwner`)can consume from one partition (or Shard what Kinesis calls it). If this consumer fails another instance of the same consumer will take over and continue processing from the `checkpoint`.
- checkpoint is the last processed event
- the shard that the consumer instance is processing is called `leaseKey` which is unique for a table.
- The data structure of the key value based document in Dynamodb would be as below,

where

`"S" - Char array`

`"N" - Number`

```
{
  "leaseOwner": {
    "S": "SmartConsumerStream_Consumer-192.168.1.83"
  },
  "checkpoint": {
    "S": "49570630332110756564477900867375857710984404992079691778"
  },
  "checkpointSubSequenceNumber": {
    "N": "0"
  },
  "leaseCounter": {
    "N": "16"
  },
  "leaseKey": {
    "S": "shardId-000000000000"
  },
  "ownerSwitchesSinceCheckpoint": {
    "N": "0"
  }
}
```

- You can use Dynamodb API to get the current offset for given `partitionKey` or `leaseKey`. You can only query by `leaseKey` because thats the indexed key in table. Its created by Kinesis-stream itself.
- You can use the [stream-driver](https://github.com/nihil-os/stream-driver) I'm writing at [here](https://github.com/nihil-os/stream-driver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eventstream/consumer/kinesis/KinesisEventStreamConsumer.java#L112), **which gives you interface to get the consumer offset very very easily.**
- Here are [kinesis-stream tests](https://github.com/nihil-os/stream-driver/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/eventstream/consumer/kinesis/KinesisEventStreamConsumerComponentSpecs.scala#L25) which might be helpful too.

### In summary, get the consumer offset using JAVA api

-- put aws credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`

```
public Map<String, String> getConsumerPosition() {
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(getOffsetConnection()); //
    Table consumerOffsetTable = dynamoDB.getTable("your_consumer_id");

    Map<String, Object> leaseOwner = consumerOffsetTable.getItem("leaseKey", "shardId-000000000000").asMap();

    return new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put(leaseOwner.get("leaseKey").toString(), leaseOwner.get("checkpoint").toString());
    }};
}

public AmazonDynamoDB getOffsetConnection() {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(getAuthProfileCredentials(), getHttpConfiguration());

    return dynamoDB;
}

private ProfileCredentialsProvider getAuthProfileCredentials() {
    return new ProfileCredentialsProvider("your-aws-auth-profile_in_~/.aws/credentials");
}


private ClientConfiguration getHttpConfiguration() {

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

    return clientConfiguration;
}
```

Hope it helps, let me know if I can help some other ways.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. Could you please look into this too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381253/how-do-i-use-the-requestshutdown-and-shutdown-to-do-graceful-shutdown-in-the-cas

Comment: Cool, I posted answer there. Let me know if that helps.